# how to switch to path instead of url in urlpatterns [django]

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

django noobie. ive been going through tutorials but in urlpatterns they use url instead of path which is now introduced in django 2.0
i want to make /appname/anything-gibberish take the user back to the view im giving in /appname/

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

i want 127.0.0.1:8000/contact/asaskhask to go to views.contact
is there any way to do this without using url and regular expression?

Comment: I would handle this in your view method, not solely with URLs.  In other words, check the parameter in your view method, and if it doesn't match, redirect to another URL

Comment: @Jason that wont work as the matching is done in the urlpattern itself. the control goes to the views only if it was successful

Comment: why a redirect rather than a 404 or some other error page?

Answer (score 6):

I am also working on django2 at the moment. You should consider investing more time in django docs

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('contact/<str:contact_name>/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    ]
```

here **str** tells django to expect a string, as i am expecting names not to have any number or special characters. if numbers only use it like `<int:contact_number>` . or the good old **slug**

Use this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters).

Oh just in case if you miss it, no more headache for matching uid, pk or token. its all inbuilt in django 2.0. yaaay

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', UserActivate.as_view(), name='activate'),
```

Answer (score -2):

i found the solution. by using `re__path` in place of `path`, you'll be able to use regular expression

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

Comment: this is wrong, eg: if your have a url like `contact/service_desk/service_guy_name` this url could spell trouble